# ASPxCheckBox in gridView keeps returning a null value

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, gridview, devexpress

I have a gridview that contains checkboxes. The problem I am having is that when I try to access my checkbox in my C# code it keeps returning a null value. Its almost as if C# does not recognise the ID value of the checkbox in the aspx.

My GridView

```
<dx:ASPxGridView ID="grvQualificationScheduleDetails" runat="server" KeyFieldName="ModuleEnrollmentId" SettingsPager-Mode="ShowAllRecords">
                                <Columns>
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Academicyear" VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Year" />
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ModuleName" VisibleIndex="1" Caption="Module Name" />
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ScheduleName" VisibleIndex="2" Caption="Schedule Name" />
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ScheduleGroupName" VisibleIndex="3" Caption="Group Name" />
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="Result" VisibleIndex="4" Caption="Status" />
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="ModuleEnrollmentId" VisibleIndex="5" Visible="false" Caption="ModuleEnrollmentId" />
                                    <dx:GridViewDataColumn FieldName="" VisibleIndex="6">
                                    <DataItemTemplate>
                                     <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="ChkSelected" OnCheckedChanged="ChkSelected_CheckedChanged" Checked='<%#((IsSelected((int)Eval("ModuleEnrollmentId"))==true))?false:true %>' AutoPostBack="true" runat="server"></dx:ASPxCheckBox>
                                   </DataItemTemplate>
                                   </dx:GridViewDataColumn>
                                  
                                </Columns>
                            </dx:ASPxGridView>
```

**My C# method**

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

        ASPxCheckBox chk = (ASPxCheckBox)grvQualificationScheduleDetails.FindControl("ChkSelected");
        chk.Checked = false; 
    }
}
```

Comment: In GridView there will be multiple rows, and  each row will have one checkbox. So You can not get the checkbox by doing FindControl on the GridView. You should do FindControl on the specific row for GridView.

Comment: I also use DevExpress - I believe that the DX grid does not maintain the data on a postback - you have to rebind. Anyway - if you have support DX KB and support are the best people to ask.